# How to restore an application's revoked Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication

I created an application based on these steps:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

In the beginning I saved the credentials.json file. Later on when using the application I still had to log into my account in the browser and provide access to it.
Later I had to play around with it, and I revoked the access here:
https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?hl=en
Now there is absolutely no way to add this access back, and the application no longer opens the browser and prompts me to give access. Instead I'm getting this:
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
which is okay, but how can I restore the grant?
Is there a way to add this access back?

Answer (score 2):

I found it already: by deleting the StoredCredential file in the tokens folder. 
Looks like this is the one that gets created when the user authorizes the app in their browser.